# How can i save a reference to an Array method?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to achieve this kind of behavior ?

Thanks in advance.

```
const filterBy = (arr, side) => {
    const reduceFunc = side === 'left' ? reduce : reduceRight;

    arr.reduceFunc(...)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just have to get a string and then use bracket notation to access the appropriate function on `Array.prototype`:

```js
const filterBy = (arr, side) => {
  const propName = side === 'left' ? 'reduce' : 'reduceRight';
  
  // silly minimal example, will simply return the last item that's iterated over:
  return arr[propName]((a, item) => item);
}
const arr = [1, 2];

// Reduces starting from left, last item iterated over will be 2:
console.log(filterBy(arr, 'left'));
// Reduces starting from right, last item iterated over will be 1:
console.log(filterBy(arr, 'right'));
```